# Calculating R^2 for linear regression: SSreg/SStot vs 1-(SSSres/SStot) leading to different results

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression

I'm trying to calculate R^2 of a regression. Looking at [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) it can be calculated either by SSreg/SStot or by 1-(SSSres/SStot). I was under the impression that I would end up with the same values, however, it seems that I have cases where the former one gives me 5%, while the latter formula I end up with -1%. Is this possible at all, and if so, under what circumstances?

The implementation is as follows:

```
r2 = np.sum(df['fi']-df['yi'].mean()) ** 2) / np.sum(df['yi']-df['yi'].mean()) ** 2)
r2 = 1 - (np.sum((df['yi']-df['fi']) ** 2) / np.sum(df['yi']-df['yi'].mean()) ** 2))
```

Is there anything wrong with it? And if not, what can explain the differences and even negative values?

**EDIT:**

Fixing the parenthesis problem, the question remains the same. The below calculations do not lead to the same result

```
r2 =     np.sum( (df['fi']-df['yi'].mean())**2 ) / \
         np.sum( (df['yi']-df['yi'].mean())**2 )
r2 = 1 - np.sum( (df['yi']-df['fi'])**2 ) / \
         np.sum( (df['yi']-df['yi'].mean())**2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have parentheses problems.  You are squaring the sums where you should be summing the squares.  The squaring should be inside the `sum` function, not outside:

```
r2 =     np.sum( (df['fi']-df['yi'].mean())**2 ) / \
         np.sum( (df['yi']-df['yi'].mean())**2 )
r2 = 1 - np.sum( (df['yi']-df['fi'])**2 ) / \
         np.sum( (df['yi']-df['yi'].mean())**2 )
```

Comment: my values are still different. The original problem remains

Comment: I don't think they're supposed to.  The article says "In some cases" and "when the relation holds, the above definition of R2 is equivalent to:".  I tried some sample data sets, and they aren't the same.  Close, but not the same.

Comment: how can I interpret a result that has 5% in one case and -1% in another?

Comment: If you have a few wild points in your predicted values that are WAY far from the actual values, then SSres could be larger than SStot, and the "1-" formulate would go negative.